# overload the $() function

Tags: jquery

Can I overload the $() function?
I want to implement such pattern $('$name') where the string starts with '$' then I return my defined result. for example:

```
function getElementByVarName(varName) {
    //return something of my own
}

var original$=$;
$=function(param) {
    if (typeof param === 'string' && param.startsWith('$')) {
        return getElementByVarName(param.substring(1));
    } else {
        original$(param);
    }
}
```

What is the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
var j = $.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    //here your new function codes

 });
 })(jQuery);
```

And orginal `$` is now `j` function

here **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/safarov/FRMG6/)**

Comment: How?.. Can you put any exapmle? I want the original behaveior to be exists - I need only overide the case of $.

Comment: I need to write a plugin or a method. I still don't understand how I can use noConflict in order to write something generic.

Comment: Thanks, But I need $ to still act as jquery and just add behaviour to $.

Answer (score 0):

What you have sketched out should work fine indeed!

EDIT: You'll want to accommodate for various arguments passed to the original function, by doing:

```
 original$.apply(original$, arguments)
```

Comment: But I think there are many options that $ can get.. and I believe there is a better way of writing it.

Comment: Such way $ will loose all its members like fn, extend and other methods. Moreover, in $(function() {<content>}) pattern, the original $ is used in <content>.